# How can I make my app permanently display volume instead of ringer?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

How can I make my app permanently display volume instead of ringer while the user is in my app. Currently when using the application the app displays the ringer sound adjuster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MPVolumeView` .

```
let volumeViewHolder = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: view.bounds.size.width - 40, height: 200))
    volumeViewHolder.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

    let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: volumeViewHolder.bounds)
    volumeView.showsRouteButton = true
    volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = true

    volumeViewHolder.addSubview(volumeView)

    view.addSubview(volumeViewHolder)
```

Its just a demo. You can have your version with frames and styling as per your requirements